[Kalman filter for radar tracking]: How to handle wrapped speed and/or range measurement model?
The Radar sensor measures range, angle, range-velocity, so it is a non-linear measurement model, and I would use UKF to handle it.
What makes it not straightforward is the wrapping measurements. Both speed and range measurements could be wrapped around, let's just consider speed first as they will have similar solutions. $v_{measured} = v_{real} \% v_{max}$. For example, if the maximum speed that can be measured by sensor is $\pm$80 km/h, then 70km/h, -90 km/h and 170 km/h vehicle would all have measurement of 70km/h.
What variant of Kalman filter is most computationally efficient to handle such situation?
My intuition is:

On receiving first measurement, use a multi-hypothesis approach, create hypotheses of the possible speeds (e.g. 70, -90, 170).
On receiving second measurement, update each hypothesis with UKF. The UKF has a modified residual/innovation computation function that calculate the minimum distance considering wrapping.
After a few measurements, if one hypothesis become dominant (reaching certain threshold), I can drop the other hypotheses to reduce number of UKF update computation.

Is this approach sound and efficient? Is there any more computationally efficient (in term of RAM and time) approach?
Please advise, thank you.

I'm no KF expert, but my intuition is that you would not want to consume UKF resources on unwrapping range and velocity. You probably want to do PRF staggering combined with a clustering algorithm to estimate the unwrapped range and velocity, and then feed that into the UKF.

This is an ambiguity-resolution problem, which is usually done at the detection stage. This is achieved either by a certain selection of waveforms or some kind of cue from another data source. Once that's done and you resolve the correct measurements, then you pass it off to the tracker.

Thank you @Envidia, for your excellent suggestions on resolving ambiguity before applying the Kalman filter. However, I am seeking a solution that involves using the Kalman filter. This is because the required update rate does not permit the use of multiple waveforms to generate a single detection.

Thank you @Baddioes, for your excellent suggestions on resolving ambiguity with PRF staggering before applying the Kalman filter. However, I am using FMCW radar and seeking a solution with the Kalman filter.

@Ewan If you have a hard limit on your update rate (which is odd since most relevant physical processes are slow compared to the timelines in a radar system), you either have a bad system design or you're using hardware that simply isn't up to do the job. Regarding FMCW, if you're doing this in any modern context, even those systems have an effective PRI/PRF that can be changed.

In case you do not want to use staggering then either of the range or Doppler must be unambiguous. Say your range in unambiguous then you can use range rate as a hint to correct the velocity estimate in your Kalman filter. I hope it makes sense.

Hi @Envidia, I am tracking vehicles up to 300km/h with 50 ms update rate using standard chirp sequence and range-doppler map, you know the drill. Not sure if this is still considered modern, is there any better waveform design for this scenario? Due to a IF bandwidth limitation, I cannot chirp very fast and end up with a quite limited max unambiguous speed.

@Ewan By "cannot chirp very fast", are you saying that your hardware can't cover the bandwidth needed, or that the receiver doesn't have a decent bandwidth? The latter dictates more what your maximum beat frequencies can be, Doppler comes down to your PRI/PRF which is independent of bandwidth. Now, if you have a data throughput issue were you simply can't process multiple PRIs and their samples quickly enough, that's another issue.

@Envidia, the way to increase unambiguous velocity, is to reduce chirp repetition time. That means, for each single chirp, I either need to have a steeper FMCW slope to cover the full RF bandwidth in a shorter time, or have the same slope to cover a reduced RF bandwidth.  The second option reduce range resolution, which is unacceptable. And the first option is even more unacceptable as it reduces max range, due to hardware's max ADC sampling rate and limited IF bandwidth. So, that's why I am left with wrapped velocity.

@Envidia, I understand that if I use another chirp sequence of a different chirp repetition time, the wrapping point will be different, and I can use the Chinese remainder theorem to solve for ambiguity. However, the drawback in that is 1) association uncertainty for nearby objects, as the second chirp sequence would be about 30 ms later, and objects' range bins would have changed. 2) Increased computation complexity. Does the industry norm consider solving ambiguity using multiple chirp sequences more computationally efficient than solving it with Kalman filtering?

@Ewan I have never seen ambiguity resolution happen at the tracking filter. The filter itself is supposed to intake what the current estimates are for a particular parameter, its job is not to resolve ambiguities. That is done at the detection stage, where the measurement data is "prepared" to tracking. If your radar's design does not allow you to be unambiguous in Doppler and/or range (which you shouldn't assume anyway), then you must resolve the ambiguities before you pass them to the tracker.
